# Transforming data to normality. What is the best function for a given case?

Tags: r, statistics, normal-distribution

Is there a function  or a package that allows to look for the best (or one of the best) variable transformation in order to make model's residuals as normal as possible?

---

For example:

```
frml = formula(some_tranformation(A) ~ B+I(B^2)+B:C+C)
model = aov(formula, data=data)
shapiro.test(residuals(model))
```

Is there a function that tells what is the function `some_transformation()` that optimizes the normality of the residuals?

Comment: Why not taking one of the many normality test and comparing each statistic by model ?

Comment: @statquant because that's a _terrible_ idea?

Comment: @hadley , please tell me more about this, I am sure I will learn a lot or more likely laught a lot

Comment: @statquant basically, normality tests are sensitive to different departures from normality than the other test. i.e. moderate kurtosis or mild skewness has little impact on a t-test, but a normality test will reject the null. It's a pretty commonly discussed topic.

Comment: @hadley, of course but this is true for anything, though if I give you a transformation that makes the residuals say lognormal and another approx normal and you use a Kolmogorov Smirnov test __hopefully__ null hyp is much more likely to be accepted on one than on the other...

Comment: @statquant but that doesn't actually matter, and now you've also introduced a multiple comparisons problem.

Comment: @hadley, reading the question asked this is what the OP asked for

Comment: @statquant that doesn't make it any more statistically valid. You might want to do some reading on the issue

Comment: Unless you give me an explicit reference I am afraid you have not make any point here...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean like the Box-Cox transformation?

```
library(car)
m0 <- lm(cycles ~ len + amp + load, Wool)
plot(m0, which=2)
```

[image]

```
# Box Cox Method, univariate
summary(p1 <- powerTransform(m0))
# bcPower Transformation to Normality 
# 
#    Est.Power Std.Err. Wald Lower Bound Wald Upper Bound
# Y1   -0.0592   0.0611          -0.1789           0.0606
# 
# Likelihood ratio tests about transformation parameters
#                              LRT df      pval
# LR test, lambda = (0)  0.9213384  1 0.3371238
# LR test, lambda = (1) 84.0756559  1 0.0000000


# fit linear model with transformed response:
coef(p1, round=TRUE)
summary(m1 <- lm(bcPower(cycles, p1$roundlam) ~ len + amp + load, Wool))
plot(m1, which=2)
```

[image]

Comment: also `MASS::boxcox()`

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately this is not a solved problem in statistics. What user @statquant has suggested is pretty much the best you can do, however it is not without its own pitfalls.

One important thing to note is that tests for normality, like `shapiro.test` are very sensitive to changes once you get reasonable sample sizes (i.e. in the hundreds), so you should not blindly rely on them.

Myself, i've thrown the problem in the too hard basket. If the data doesn't look at least normally distributed, then I would try to find a *non-parametric* version of the statistics you want to run on the data.